# Preventing overlap of section and figure

Tags: titlesec, tufte

I used `titlesec` package to produce a section style which takes all paper width. when I use `maginfigure` environment in `tufte-book` package sometimes my figure and my section overlap.

[image]

How can I prevent that happening??

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{biditufte-book}

% add numbers to chapters, sections, subsections
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\usepackage{ptext}
\usepackage{tikz}



\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Tahoma}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION STYLING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newlength\outermargin
\newlength\innermargin
\setlength{\innermargin}{1in}
\setlength{\outermargin}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\textwidth-\innermargin\relax}
\titleformat{\section}%
 {\normalfont\Large\color{purple}\setlength\fboxrule{0.8pt}}% format applied to label+text
 {\llap{\colorbox{red}{\makebox[\outermargin][l]{\raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height+\fboxrule][\dimexpr\depth+\fboxrule]%
 {\vphantom{lp}\color{white}\bfseries\thesection\enspace}}}}}% label
 {0pt}% horizontal separation between label and title body
{\rlap{\hspace{-\fboxrule}\framebox[\dimexpr\linewidth + 2\fboxrule\relax][l]{\vphantom{lp}}\colorbox{orange}{\makebox[\outermargin][l]{\raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height+\fboxrule][\dimexpr\depth+\fboxrule]%
 {\vphantom{lp}}}}}\enspace}% before the title body
[]


\begin{document}
\chapter{فصل}
\section{مقدمه}
\begin{marginfigure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{This is a margin figure. The helix is defined by $x = \cos(2\pi z)$, $y = \sin(2\pi z)$, and $z = [0, 2.7]$.}
\label{fig:marginfig}
\end{marginfigure}
\ptext[4]
\subsection{معرفنامه}
\ptext[1-10]
\section{سرانجام}
\end{document}
```